# Installing SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition: How to repair the visual studio runtime (library) 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 X64 Minimum Runtime'?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a fully updated Visual Studio Professional 2017 installed, and I am now trying to install [SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-tools), but receive the following error message (translated to English by me) and the installation of the SQL server aborts:

> The Visual Studio-Runtime Microsoft "Visual C++ 2019 X64 Minimum Runtime - 14.22.27821" has to be repaired.

The error message points me to a [guide how to repair or remove programs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028054/windows-10-repair-or-remove-programs), so I tried reinstalling SQL Server 2017 and Visual Studio, but both does not help, the error persists.

**Is there anything else I could try to fix that broken runtime library?** Does it matter that I also have/had the community version of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) installed?

Comment: This [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/repair-apps-and-programs-in-windows-10-e90eefe4-d0a2-7c1b-dd59-949a9030f317) will help in Repair apps and programs in Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what exactly solved my problem, what I tried doing is the following

1. Under `Apps & features` within the Windows `Settings`, I "repaired" all apps with a similar name to the error message, i.e. everything of the kind `Microsoft Visual C++ 20xx Redistributable (x86)` with `xx`being a 2-digit year, or a year range such as `15-2019`.
2. Deinstalled the Visual Studio Community Edition.
3. Reboot the system multiple times afterwards and inbetween.

Point 2 might have just [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) to ease my mind, but all of **this did not solve the issue yet.**

Eventually I decided to install [SQL Server 2017 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) rather than [SQL Server 2017 Developer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-tools) which miraculously worked. I can not rule out that my IT department solved it by obtaining additional licenses, since I am not able to figure out the exact time when the new keys got active.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem.

I just updated my version of Visual Studio 2017 Community edition using the Visual Studio Installer and the issue went away.